# Registering Devise use as an initial unapproved state

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, before-filter

I have added a field called `isAdmin` to  my user controller and I want it so chose a friendly message on any page that has `before_filter :authenticate_user!` if the user is not admin.

How do I override the before filter so that it also checks if the user is admin?

I've seen example on using cancan, but I only want admin users to do anything in my app, but I want new admin users to not be sett as admin but then be confirmed by another admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have to overwrite the method by create a ruby file in your Rails app folder ( so that the file in Gem folder will be overwritten) :

1.the original authenticate_user! method is defined in:

```
# GEM_HOME/gems/cancan-2.0.x/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb 

1 module Devise
2   module Controllers
3     # Those helpers are convenience methods added to ApplicationController.
4     module Helpers
...   #.... some code and comments
42       def self.define_helpers(mapping) #:nodoc:
43         mapping = mapping.name
44
45         class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
46           def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
47             opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
48             warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
49           end
```

2.so we could define our own:

```
# RAILS_APP/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb
1 module Devise
2   module Controllers
3     # Those helpers are convenience methods added to ApplicationController.
4     module Helpers
5       def authenticate_user!(opts={})
6         authenticate_if_the_user_is_admin  # PUT your hook here.
7         opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
8         warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
9         # other code...
10      end
11    end
12  end
13end
```

NOT tested.  :-)